# How can i add lightning:select in recordEditForm's one of input field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

How can i added lightning:select in recordEditForm's one of input field which is the simple input field?
Can i change field from input to select in recordEditForm?

This is input field from lightning:recordEditForm.

[image]

and This the lightning:select field I want to added in Lightning:recordEditForm.

[image]

Here is the code i want to remove input field and put select field.
can i still get the saved value when i open recordEditForm.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this was to create a combobox and hide the actual text field that you want to set.

Then the combobox changes set the value into a variable.  In the submit method you grab the value from that variable and set the field value in the form to that variable prior to the actual submit.

HTML lightning record edit Form

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Object Name__c" record-type-id="01253000000564gAAA" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit={handleSubmit} >
    <lightning-combobox  name="Name1" label="Name 1" value={name1Value} placeholder="Select Name 1" options={name1Options} onchange={handleName1Change} ></lightning-combobox>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name1__c" class="slds-hidden"> </lightning-input-field>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeModal} title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new"></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Javascript Changes

Handle change method just writes the value into the variable

```javascript
handleName1Change(event) {
    this.name1Value = event.detail.value;
}
```

Submit method just sets the field value to the value of the variable that holds the combobox selection

```javascript
handleSubmit(event){
    // stop the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    //Get the fields       
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    //Set the field for the hidden lightning-input-field
    fields.Name1__c = this.name1Value;
    //Submit the form
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```